# Contour command in Spatial Ecology's GME

Tags: dem, contour, command-line, gme

Has anyone been successful using the contour command from GME (Geospatial Modelling Environment)? I'm trying to create contours out of a DEM. I know you can do it in ArcGIS with 3D or Spatial Analyst extension but I don't have them hence giving GME a try.

I've tried it and got the following errors:

> Error: The specified workspace does not exist. Cannot open raster dataset: C:\Users\as\Documents\Columbia Test.gdb!Columbia10M_Elevation
>
> Error: The command text could not be interpreted. Please check the syntax of the command.
>
> Error: An important error has occurred. Please include the information below if you submit a query about this error.
>   The XY domain on the spatial reference is not set or invalid.

I read the help manual and it says that the algorithm hasn't been widely tested. So I'm thinking that it might not be the best tool for getting contours from DEMs.

Any suggestions on a fix or a different work around in lieu of Spatial Analyst?

**Update 9/8/14:**

GME's developer sent me the following:

> "Unfortunately GME is not designed to work with GDB-based rasters. You would have to export to one of the file-based formats (img, tif, or grid) if you want to use GME. I will have a look at adding that functionality into a future release."

Comment: You can also generate contours using QGIS. There are several tools available in it to generate contours from a DEM: GRASS, SAGA, and the contour plugin.